# Embedding externally generated C-code within OpenModelica models

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

We are working with a tool that generates C-code. For example, the C-code could be for the logic: "if a sensor is activated, turn on the LED bulb". The code can be saved into a function that can be called from outside. What is the best way to embed this kind of external C-code into the rest of the Modelica model?  How can we compile this code along with the rest of the .mo files preferably using OM Shell script and omc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly put C code in external functions or link with a library.

See:

- https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch12.html#external-function-interface
- https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch12.html#external-objects

As examples see some of our tests from the testsuite:

- https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/blob/master/testsuite/simulation/modelica/

Simple example:

- https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/blob/master/testsuite/simulation/modelica/external_functions/ExternalLibraries.mo
- https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/blob/master/testsuite/simulation/modelica/external_functions/ExternalLibraries.mos
- https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/blob/master/testsuite/simulation/modelica/external_functions/ExternalFunc1.c
- https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/blob/master/testsuite/simulation/modelica/external_functions/ExternalFunc2.c

Some advanced libraries:

- https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/Modelica_DeviceDrivers
- https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/ExternData